# Tab bar view is not rendering on loading the app in release mode

Tags: flutter, tabs, flutter-layout, tabview, hot-reload

When I open app in realease mode the tab bar view does not render itself until I click on search field that rebuild the widget then it works

```
body: Column(
    children: [
      XEappBar(
        onDrawerPress: () {
          _key.currentState!.openDrawer();
        },
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabcontroller,
          children: const [HomePage(), WishListPage()],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: are you initializing it in InitState

Comment: I am only initializing the tabController in initstate, but the hompage is using future builder